# wordpress post while loop inside jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i want to loop all post title inside javascript to build my gallery but it does not works i get strange output
**My code** :

```
  <?php
        query_posts(array( 
            'post_type' => 'musings'
        ) );  
         while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $title = the_title();
        $desc = the_content();
        $galleryslider .= "{
                        'title'         : '".$title."',
                        'description'   : '".$desc."',
                        'thumbnail'     : ['images/small/1.jpg', 'images/small/2.jpg'],
                        'large'         : ['images/large/1.jpg', 'images/large/2.jpg'],
                        'button_list'   :
                        [
                            { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                            { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                        ],
                        'tags'          : ['Portrait']
                    },";
     endwhile;
     $galleryslider = rtrim($galleryslider,',');
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        <?php echo $finalslider;?>
    });
    </script>
```

**Expected out put**

```
{
                'title'         : 'post 1 title',
                'description'   : 'post 1 desc',
                'thumbnail'     : ['images/small/1.jpg', 'images/small/2.jpg'],
                'large'         : ['images/large/1.jpg', 'images/large/2.jpg'],
                'button_list'   :
                [
                    { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                    { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                ],
                'tags'          : ['Portrait']
            },{
                'title'         : 'post 2 title',
                'description'   : 'post 2 desc',
                'thumbnail'     : ['images/small/1.jpg', 'images/small/2.jpg'],
                'large'         : ['images/large/1.jpg', 'images/large/2.jpg'],
                'button_list'   :
                [
                    { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                    { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                ],
                'tags'          : ['Portrait']
            }
```

**Ouptut i get** (wordress pages show title and desc above javasscript but value on title and desc inside javascrit is blank see below code)

```
{
                'title'         : '',
                'description'   : '',
                'thumbnail'     : ['images/small/1.jpg', 'images/small/2.jpg'],
                'large'         : ['images/large/1.jpg', 'images/large/2.jpg'],
                'button_list'   :
                [
                    { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                    { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                ],
                'tags'          : ['Portrait']
            },{
                'title'         : '',
                'description'   : '',
                'thumbnail'     : ['images/small/1.jpg', 'images/small/2.jpg'],
                'large'         : ['images/large/1.jpg', 'images/large/2.jpg'],
                'button_list'   :
                [
                    { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                    { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                ],
                'tags'          : ['Portrait']
            }
```

Comment: query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'musing',   ) );  has a comma that it shouldn't have I think.

Comment: Could you give us an example of output you are expecting?

Comment: removed that i am not getting title inside jquery 'title'         :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little I know about Wordpress, try either echoing the data right out or save to the output buffer and echo later. Also, you may have to return false on the `the_title()` in order to use `strip_tags()`. Also, `$desc` does not appear to be define.:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    query_posts(array('post_type' => 'musing'));

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        {
            // the_title() can use a false to return the value for use with strip_tags (apparently)
            'title'         : '<?php echo stripslashes(the_title(false)); ?>',
            // Where is this $desc coming from?
            'description'   : '<?php echo $desc; ?>',
            'thumbnail'     : ['images/small/1.jpg', 'images/small/2.jpg'],
            'large'         : ['images/large/1.jpg', 'images/large/2.jpg'],
            'button_list'   : [
                { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
            ],
            'tags'          : ['Portrait']
        }, <?php
    endwhile;
    $data   =   ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            <?php echo $data; ?>
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? What other way would you like to do it?

Comment: it means to say that using ob_get_contents is right way , can we do some changes in wp query to get results

Comment: Using the output buffer just basically writes to memory before it writes to the page, then you assign the contents to a variable. It's basically the same thing you are doing, however, some of the wp functions echo which you can not assign to a variable. You can change the functions to return and not echo (according to the manual) then what you have "should" work

Comment: What I have done is fine, there is nothing wrong with using it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you had to change quite so much of your code as you appear to have simply not been using the right Wordpress functions/not passing the right arguments to them. By default the_title() & the_content() cause display at run time.

To make use of them programmatically you need something like this:

```
<?php
        query_posts(array( 
            'post_type' => 'musings'
        ) );  
         while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $title = the_title(false);
        $desc = get_the_content();
        $galleryslider .= "{

        ...
```

Your original code sample then echoes out a $finalslider variable - is that a typo? If not how is that getting set when you're using $galleryslider in the build up